# Slow loading issues in edge and brave browsers when iterating over sql resource

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, chromium, browser-cache, brave

I have been trying to fix extremely slow loading on my site until I have just tested it in another browser (opera) and it pings! No wait whatsoever. However in Edge and Brave it hangs for minutes... I am using php / xammp and the site is loading an sql resource (say, 50-100 results), then when iterating over it with simple markup like a <p>tag with a variable from the resource It just takes forever, or doesn't work at all. How can this be - I have tried clearing my cache but that hasn't worked plus I never use Brave. Also I have  tested it in Firefox and it is lightning fast, just like on Opera

Edit: I understand that the iteration over an SQL resource happens server-side, and outputs before it is rendered in the browser, but that is what is puzzling me.

Comment: It is likely an incompatibility in your site.  Edge and Chrome load fast here (multiple systems and Chrome on Windows and Linux both)

Comment: Hi @John thanks, could you expand a little? I appreciate it might be to do with the browser and its connection to the server?

Comment: FYI the site works fine and I can print_r the sql resource in the browser. But once I iterate (foreach) over the resource it kills the site. Just on those browsers though

Comment: I just use regular user sites and browsers work fine. I am using Chrome in Kali here to post and run in SuperUser.  Edge in Windows 11, 10 and 7 and Edge is fast as well.

Comment: My concern is with my site and not all sites - and only when I loop over an SQL resource to create markup

Comment: I cannot (and probably we cannot ) help you with your site. No way to do that.

Comment: Yep, I have posted this on Stack too.. I am flummoxed. Will look up compatibility